# How to present a flag in python?

Tags: python

Like the following C# code:

```
[Flags]
public enum CandleFlags : short
{
    /// <summary>No flags set</summary>
    None = 0x00,

    /// <summary>IsDoji</summary>
    Doji = 0x01,

    /// <summary>IsHammer</summary>
    Hammer = 0x02,
```

.....

Flag is not only enum since one object can have several flags, like it can be of type doji and hammer?

Shall I just use int?

Comment: all it is in C# is an int ... and it does bitwise and against the flags ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CandleFlags:
      DOJI= 0x01
      HAMMER=0x02
      SOMETHING=0x04 

print CandleValue & CandleFlags.DOJI # doji bit is set
print CandleValue & CandleFlags.SOMETHING #something bit is set
print CandleValue & ~CandleFlags.HAMMER # Hammer bit is not set
```

maybe?

you can further expand upon this concept with something like

```
class FlagChecker:
    def __init__(self,flags):
       self.flags = flags
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
       if attr.startswith("is"):
          flg = getattr(self.flags,attr[2:].upper(),0)
          return lambda v:bool(v & flg)

checker = FlagChecker(CandleFlags)
print checker.isHammer(candleValue)
print not checker.isDoji(candleValue)
print checker.isYellow(candleValue) #always false ... no YELLOW flag
```

Comment: I think this is good enough: an int and a class of constant flags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
class CandleFlags:
    is_doji = False
    is_hammer = False

flags = CandleFlags()
flags.is_doji = True
```